# Colorado insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this bug in my backyard, but was unable to identify it. Thanks for any hint!

Edit : I live in the south east suburbs of Denver, Centennial.
So this is quite an urban area. I found this bug on my deck, and it escaped going under my deck. The board in the pictures are from my deck (composite, not real wood). My backyard is quite small, mostly grass and not a lot of flowers. The bug's body is around 3/4".

[image]

Comment: a better location and a descripion of the area you found it will help in identifying the insect,please edit more information into your question.

Comment: Thank you, done.

Comment: How big is this bug approximately?

Comment: Around 3/4" - Edited my description as well. Thank you.